# Match a specific pattern in a string

Tags: java

I have a string err = `Duplicate value(s) are not allowed for attribute(s): { a_id_1_a_name_1 dup key { "1", "yes" }`

How can I check that my string has a pattern `anyString_digit_anystring_digit`

Here `anyString` means any word or character.

Comment: Have a look to regex.

Comment: [This site](https://www.jrebel.com/blog/java-regular-expressions-cheat-sheet) has a cheat sheet PDF of regex expressions you can download if you would like.

Comment: The class you're looking for is [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: If it's truly "any string" (including the empty string, strings containing spaces, etc.) you're trying to match, then the regex `_\d_.*_\d` will match what you want.

Comment: Seems resolving problem in wrong place. Analyze XxxxxxException object.